# uses of creating a thread and Blocking UI

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

I have started a special course in multithreading but I have some fundamental issues I want to clear up.  say I have a thread

```
Thread t1 = new Thread(() =>  
            {
                Thread.CurrentThread.IsBackground = true;
                IsCancel = false;
                this.workProj.DoWorkWithRefSync(ref IsCancel); 
            });             
t1.Start();
```

Followed by

```
while(t1.IsAlive)
{
}
```

or

```
t1.Join();
```

or

```
myAutoResetEvent.WaitOne();  // myAutoResetEvent.Set() called in thread when it finished processing
```

I am not sure but, this might not be a good example but looking forward to one.
I know that they are all some form of signaling from the background thread to inform the calling/UI thread that the work has completed.
 But using them end up blocking the UI until the thread completes. So I would like to know a real life scenario implementation of this.
I am thinking why not just run this process on the UI thread since you don't mind blocking it.
Edit: In otherwords, I am looking for the real uses of these blocking elements such as thread.Join() etc

Comment: in c# 5.0 you'd use async/await,c# 4.0 you'd use Task with continuation, prior to it you'd use background-worker or Thread or ThreadPool with some kind of notification asynchronously not synchronously waiting.

Comment: In general, using threads to run background tasks in a UI application, then blocking the UI thread while the task completes is a *very bad idea*. You're not pumping messages, the application becomes unresponsive. You can hack round it with things like `Application.DoEvents()` in your `while(alive)` block, but this causes more problems than it solves. As a rule, in any UI application, the main UI thread should be responsive and able to pump messages at all times.

Comment: t1.Join() is a blocking call. It actually waits for the previous call started by Thread t1 to finish.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your contribution, what I am not really able to get around is the actual significance of t1.join(). If the whole purpose of creating a thread is not to block the UI, why would someone then block it again? I am still trying to process the answer below

Comment: @electricalbah, did you make up this example yourself? Or have you seen it in the course you're studying?

Comment: "If the whole purpose of creating a thread is not to block the UI, why would someone then block it" - A well thought out program should not block. If the above code rings some alarms, that is because it should. The example you posted I usually see in Console apps just for learning/testing purposes so the main thread doesn't exit before the new thread. If this is UI code, or code for a non-academic purpose, I would be worried.

Comment: @Sperry I think that might be the answer. After looking through the samples I have and also from other books, I did note that all the patterns that match this code are console apps. So I agree thats its only for learning purpose in Console apps.

Answer (score 2):

A real life scenario relevant to your example would be where the reference to the thread is stored in a member of the window class, and it gets checked or waited for if some event triggers such as closing the window or the application exiting.

pseudo code:

```
class Window
{
     private Thread _thread = null;

     public void OnButtonClick()
     {
         _thread = CreateAndStartThread();
     }

     public void OnCloseWindow()
     {
         if(null != _thread)
             _thread.Wait();
     }
}
```

Comment: Yes - a classic 'failure to shutdown' risk.

Comment: Martin :) this is just to demonstrate where the reference to the thread maybe stored, and is not a fully designed defensive code :)